# redirect from old URL structure

Tags: redirect

i've just rebuilt a site with a couple of hundred products, and now i need to redirect the old URLs..
i'm using the Redirection plugin, but i'm not sure how to setup the redirects correctly ...

the old URLs were in the format
`/11/1222/our-products/product-name/?mobi=1`

the new URLs need to be the much simpler  `/product/product-name`

can anyone help me with the settings/regex to make this work?

Comment: Your regex would probably be something like `^/\d+/\d+/our-products/([^/]+)/.*` and the replacement would be `/product/$1`. You should check with the plugin's support team, though. You can test regexes online - here's one option: https://www.regextester.com/ (note that you need to escape some characters, particular `/`, with ` \ ` on that site).

Comment: thanks Pat... the bit with $1 is what i was missing i think... is that standard way of keeping parts of the term?
i'll try playing with that and see if it works...

Comment: Yes, substitution is usually done with `$1`, `$2`, ...etc. (Some systems—lookin' at you, vim—use `\1`, `\2`, etc.) [Regex Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp)